# Anaconda requirements file to install mixed packages

Tags: python, anaconda, package-managers

I'm using the [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda) platform to manage a Python environment. I've [learned](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/conda/PiM9sjWyXFU) that I can create a [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file of all the packages currently installed in my environment (lets call it `test-env`) with:

```
$ conda list -e > req.txt
```

which I can later use to re-create said environment from scratch with:

```
$ conda create -n test-env --file req.txt
```

This last command works just fine with regular packages, i.e. those that can be installed via:

```
$ conda install <package>
```

but it fails with packages that need to be installed from [Anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org). These latter packages must be [installed with the command](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-a-package-from-anaconda-org):

```
$ conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/<profile> <package>
```

Is there a way to generate a `requirements.txt` file that will work on both types of packages?